# Use dollar sign in verbatim environment within auctex

Tags: listings, environments, emacs, auctex

I am using something similar to the following,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{shellsession}[1][]
{\lstset{language=bash
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    #1
  }}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{shellsession}
  $ some code
\end{shellsession}
\end{document}
```

This gives the output I am looking for.

My problem stems from the fact that Emacs thinks that I am inside of math mode because of the `$` within the `shellsession` environment, giving me a false error. Is there a way to make emacs realize that I am inside of a verbatim like environment?